# Is there a way, in a list of jobs, to change a job's parameter to required?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I am using the script console of hudson and jenkins.

And I need make a parameter called `"NAME"` become required at the jobs where that parameter already exists. But I do not know any method that can help me.

```
def instance = hudson.model.Hudson.instance;
def allJobs = instance.getView("All");

allJobs.items.each {

    if (it.containsParameter('NAME')){ /// this exists?
        println(it.getName());

        it.set??? /// what can I do?
    }
}
```

I need that way for when someone excute the job the parameter `"NAME"` do not be empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the desired result with below code:

```
def instance = hudson.model.Hudson.instance;
def allJobs = instance.getView("All");

allJobs.items.each {

    prop = it.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
    if(prop != null) {
        for(param in prop.getParameterDefinitions()) {
            try {
              if(param.name.equals('NAME')){
                println(it.name + ":" + param.name + " " + param.defaultValue)
                if(!param.defaultValue.trim()){
                    println("default value is blank")
                }
              }

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
              println e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do want not define a default value but a required value